# MongoDB data is deleting automatically

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2

I am very confused about the MongoDB behavior I am facing these days. I am running a python application on a ubuntu server of aws ec2 instance. It happened that the whole database my application is connected with is deleted automatically.

Comment: This might help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587274/mongodb-database-deleted-automatically#:~:text=Answer%20is%20YES%20Mongodb%20is,security%20groups%20stop%20doing%20that.